# Rounding up a column

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to pandas python and I am having difficulties trying to round up all the values in the column. For example,

```
Example
88.9
88.1
90.2
45.1
```

I tried using my current code below, but it gave me:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'rint'

```
 df.Example = df.Example.round()
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.ceil`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ceil.html#numpy.ceil):

```
In [80]: import numpy as np

In [81]: np.ceil(df.Example)
Out[81]: 
0    89.0
1    89.0
2    91.0
3    46.0
Name: Example, dtype: float64
```

depending on what you like, you could also change the type:

```
In [82]: np.ceil(df.Example).astype(int)
Out[82]: 
0    89
1    89
2    91
3    46
Name: Example, dtype: int64
```

---

**Edit**

Your error message indicates you're trying just to round (not necessarily up), but are having a type problem. You can solve it like so:

```
In [84]: df.Example.astype(float).round()
Out[84]: 
0    89.0
1    88.0
2    90.0
3    45.0
Name: Example, dtype: float64
```

Here, too, you can cast at the end to an integer type:

```
In [85]: df.Example.astype(float).round().astype(int)
Out[85]: 
0    89
1    88
2    90
3    45
Name: Example, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Hey Ami, i tried df.Example.astype(float).round() but it gave me .0 decimal point. Is there any way to remove the decimal point and just the integer?

Comment: @JasonChingYuk As I noted in the answer beforehand, append to it `.astype(int)` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have privilege to comment. Mine is not a new answer. It is a compare of two answers. Only one of them worked as below.

1. First I tried this https://datatofish.com/round-values-pandas-dataframe/

   df['DataFrame column'].apply(np.ceil)

It did not work for me.

2. Then I tried the above answer

   np.ceil(df.Example).astype(int)

It worked.

I hope this will help someone.